# short circuit time constants method (SCTC)

Tags: amplifier, small-signal

Why does the short circuit time constants method (SCTC) apply to large valued capacitances used for coupling or bypass purposes in a small-signal amplifier?

Comment: Never heard of it. Please provide a link to what your title suggests you are talking about.

Comment: [here](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/fa14/lectures/Lecture15-Short%20Circuit%20Time%20Constant%20(SCTC).pdf)

Comment: "To choose capacitor values, the short-circuit time constant
 (SCTC) method is used: each capacitor is considered
 separately with all other capacitors replaced by short
 circuits. "

Comment: I never knowingly use it. I solve using different methods.